# Why isn't zIndex working in React Native?

Tags: ios, react-native, z-index

I've been trying to use the property `zIndex` on a `ScrollView` but it doesn't seem to be working. When I apply `zIndex` it looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, the `ScrollView` is being blocked by the input. I want the effect of having the `ScrollView` completely cover the other input when the suggestions come up, with `zIndex`. Here's what I have right now:

```
<View>
    <Input
        value={this.state.inputValue}
        style={styles._input}
        inputStyle={styles._text}
        onChangeText={this.handleChangeText}
        {...this.props}
    />
    <View style={styles._spacing}></View>
    {predictions.length ?
        <ScrollView
            style={styles._scroll}
        >
            {predictions.map(this.renderPrediction)}
        </ScrollView>
    : null}
</View>
```

Note that `Input` is a separate component that renders a specific `TextInput`. Also, `this.renderPrediction` returns this:

```
<Text
    style={styles._text}
    key={index}
    onPress={this.handlePredictionPress.bind(null, prediction.description)}
>
    {prediction.description}
</Text>
```

And finally here are my styles:

```
const styles = EStyleSheet.create({
    input: StyleSheet.flatten([inputStyle]),
    text: {
        fontSize: 15,
    },

    spacing: {
        height: 10
    },

    scroll: {
        position: "absolute",
        zIndex: 10,
        width: "80%",
        top: 50,
        backgroundColor: "white"
    }
});
```

Why isn't my `zIndex` attempt working and how can I get it to work as desired?

Answer (score 0):

According to your image it looks like the `zIndex` is working as expected, the `ScrollView` is over the input. But the white background didn't catch.

Use `contentContainerStyle` for the background color behind the items.

```
<ScrollView style={styles._scroll} contentContainerStyle={styles._contentContainer} >

...
contentContainer: {backgroundColor: "white"}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but this doesn't work. IIRC, I've tried it before, and the zIndex, (although it seems to be working) isn't, as seen here: http://imgur.com/a/o3lwS

Comment: It did work, it hid the `TextInput`'s text. But it looks like Android's underline in the `TextInput` isn't affected by the zIndex for some reason. I would set it to transparent (`underlineColorAndroid='rgba(0,0,0,0)'`) and recreate it with `borderBottom`.

Comment: But I'm not on Android. It didn't hide the input text, it's still visible. The underline under the input is still visible too.

Comment: Sorry didn't notice the text from the input is still a little visible in your image. In that case, could you add `inputStyle` to your code?

Comment: `inputStyle` is applied to the underlying `TextInput` of `Input`. How should I style it?

Comment: Just add the code of `Input` and `inputStyle` to your question so we get the full picture.